# How to assign FormGroup's formGroupNames to my model

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following component:

```
export class ProvidersComponent implements OnInit {

public providerFormGroup: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
            private dlService: DataListingService,
            private tbaService: TopBarActionsService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.populateForm();
    this.subscribeToTopBarAction();
}

populateForm(): void {
    this.providerFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        providerInformation: this.fb.group({
            Name: [''],
            FriendlyName: [''],
            Since: [Date.now],
            Untill: [''],
            CompanyRegistrationNumber: [''],
            VatRegistrationNumber: [''],
            TfgUniqueReferenceNumber: ['']
        }),
        contactInformation: this.fb.group({
            PhysicalAsPostal: [false],
            PhysicalAddressLine1: [''],
            PhysicalAddressLine2: [''],
            PhysicalAddressLine3: [''],
            PhysicalCityTown: [''],
            PhysicalPostalCode: [''],
            PostalAddressLine1: [''],
            PostalAddressLine2: [''],
            PostalAddressLine3: [''],
            PostalCityTown: [''],
            PostalPostalCode: [''],
            EmailAddress: [''],
            ContactNumber: [''],
            AlternativeContactNumber: ['']
        }),
        contactPeople: this.fb.group({
            ContactPeople: [''],
            Role: [''],
            Title: [''],
            Initials: [''],
            Name: [''],
            Surname: [''],
            EmailAddress: [''],
            ContactNumber: [''],
            AlternativeContactNumber: ['']
        })
    });
}

onSubmit(): void {
    //let provider: Provider = Object.assign({}, this.providerFormGroup.value);
    let provider: Provider = new Provider();
    provider = this.providerFormGroup.value;
    console.log(provider.FriendlyName);
}
}
```

The following template file:

```
<form [formGroup]="providerFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ngb-tabset>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
          <div class="tablinks" (click)="activateTab(0)">
            Provider information
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="tabcontent">
            <div formGroupName="providerInformation" class="halfsize">
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Name</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="Name" placeholder="Mobile Telecommunications Network" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Short name</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="FriendlyName" placeholder="MTN" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="half">
                  <label>
                    <strong>Provider since</strong>
                    <input type="date" formControlName="Since" placeholder="1 January 2019" />
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                  <label>
                    <strong>Provider untill</strong>
                    <input type="date" formControlName="Untill" />
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Company registration number</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="CompanyRegistrationNumber" placeholder="0000007891234" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>VAT registration number</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="VatRegistrationNumber" placeholder="121 000 345" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>TFG's unique reference at the provider</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="TfgUniqueReferenceNumber" placeholder="MTNO2O" />
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
          <div class="tablinks" (click)="activateTab(1)">
            Provider contact infromation
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="tabcontent">
            <div class="halfsize" formGroupName="contactInformation">
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Physical Address</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="PhysicalAddressLine1" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <input type="text" formControlName="PhysicalAddressLine2" />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <input type="text" formControlName="PhysicalAddressLine3" />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="half">
                  <label>
                    <strong>City/Town</strong>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="PhysicalCityTown" />
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                  <label>
                    <strong>Postal Code</strong>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="PhysicalPostalCode" />
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="left">
                  <label>Use the physical address as the postal address?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                  <tfg-toggle formControlName="PhysicalAsPostal" [onText]="'Yes'" [offText]="'No'"></tfg-toggle>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Postal Address</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="PostalAddressLine1" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <input type="text" formControlName="PostalAddressLine2" />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <input type="text" formControlName="PostalAddressLine3" />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="half">
                  <label>
                    <strong>City/Town</strong>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="PostalCityTown" />
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                  <label>
                    <strong>Postal Code</strong>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="PostalPostalCode" />
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Email address</strong>
                  <input type="email" formControlName="EmailAddress">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Contact Number</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="ContactNumber" placeholder="+27 845880635" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Alternative Contact Number (optional)</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="AlternativeContactNumber" placeholder="+27 845880635" />
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
          <div class="tablinks" (click)="activateTab(2)">
            Contact people at the provider
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="tabcontent">
            <div class="half" formGroupName="contactPeople">
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Contact People</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="ContactPeople" placeholder="John Doe">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Role</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="Role" placeholder="Sales consultant" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Title</strong>
                  <select id="title" formControlName="Title">
                    <option disabled selected>-- Please select --</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let title of titles" [ngValue]="title.Id">
                      {{title.TitleDescription}}
                    </option>
                  </select>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Initials</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="Initials" placeholder="JD" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Name</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="Name" placeholder="John" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Surname</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="Surname" placeholder="Doe" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Email address</strong>
                  <input type="email" formControlName="EmailAddress" placeholder="johndoe@email.com" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Contact Number</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="ContactNumber" placeholder="+27 845880635" />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <label>
                  <strong>Alternative Contact Number (optional)</strong>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="AlternativeContactNumber" placeholder="+27 845880635" />
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
          <div class="tablinks" (click)="activateTab(3)">
            Provider's Financial Accounts at TFG
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="tabcontent">
            <div formGrouName="financialAccounts">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="half">

                </div>
                <div class="half">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
          <div class="tablinks" (click)="activateTab(4)">
            Saving the provider
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <div class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Saving the provider</h3>
            <p>Financial accounts (note these are not bank accounts) are created at TFG for each provider
              to facilitate the reconciliation of funds paid by the Provider to TFG and by TFG to the Provider.
              At least one account must be specified for a provider.
            </p>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
  </form>
```

And finally, the model I want this form to represent and be able to assign to:

```
export class Provider {
  public Id: string;
  public Name: string;
  public FriendlyName: string;
  public CompanyRegistrationNumber: string;
  public VatRegistrationNumber: string;
  public TfgUniqueReferenceNumber: string;
  public Since: Date;
  public Until: Date;
  public DefaultBillingDay: number;
  public DefaultProvisioningDay: number;
  public AllowsToProvisionProRata: boolean;
  public AllowsToBillProRata: boolean;
  public EmailAddress: string;
  public DateCreated: Date;
  public DateModified: Date;
  public UserCreated: string;
  public UserModified: string;
  public IsRetired: boolean;
  public ImageUrl: string;
  public ContactNumber1: ContactNumber;
  public ContactNumber2: ContactNumber;
  public PhysicalAddress: Address;
  public PostalAddress: Address;
  public FinancialSystemAccount: FinancialSystemAccount;
  public WholesaleProducts: Array<WholesaleProduct>;
  public ContactPeople: Array<ContactPerson>;
  public Batches: Array<Batch>;
  public BatchCandidates: Array<BatchCandidate>;
  public AllowableBatchTypes: Array<BatchType>;
}
```

I have tried both of the following, but the result in `console` is always `undefined`.

```
let provider: Provider = Object.assign({}, this.providerFormGroup.value);
let provider: Provider = new Provider();
provider = this.providerFormGroup.value;
console.log(provider.FriendlyName);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form value does not match your class. In your form you have nested groups: `providerInformation`, `contactInformation` and `contactPeople`. Those do not exist in your class.

Also I see some issue at least with one of your form controls... you have used `Untill`, even though in your class, the property is `Until`

The simplest solution is to build your form as such, that is assignable as is to your model right out of the box. Otherwise you need to map the properties yourself, that can get ugly and seems unneccessary when you can build your form so that it matches your model.

And as a note as why your console log prints undefined, is because your `FriendlyName` is actually in one of those nested groups, so if you were to do the following, you wouldn't get `undefined`:

```
let provider: Provider = Object.assign({}, this.providerFormGroup.value);
console.log(provider.providerInformation.FriendlyName); // not undefined!
```

But with that your compiler will complain that `providerInformation` does not exist in `Provider`. Which is correct of course.

Comment: Should I remove the 'formGroupNames' from my form then?

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion, and in my opinion the most cleanest way to do this. And also remember to check that your form control names match with your model :)

Comment: Aaaarggghhh. I thought that the formGroupNames are a nice way of grouping these controls.  Will give it a try quick

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with the grouping, you can do that, but then you need to map the form object to your model, which can get messy. You can go either way though ;)